# TYPO3 resets all DateTimes in one Field from time to time

Tags: typo3, extbase

I've got a problem with an extbase extension I wrote some months ago:
Normaly everything works fine, but at some point, the system updates ALL DateTime info of a certain field back to the 1.1.1970, in everey entry of the table.

There is a model for courses. Those contain three DateTime fields. The date, the begin and the end of the course. The Problem happens only in the date field. In the model, it is defined as so:

```
/**
 * date
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $date = NULL;


**
 * Returns the date
 *
 * @return \DateTime $date
 */
public function getDate() {
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Sets the date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return void
 */
public function setDate(\DateTime $date) {
    $this->date = $date;
}
```

In the TCA, the definition is:

```
    'date' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'shortend for example',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 7,
            'eval' => 'date',
            'checkbox' => 1,
            'default' => time()
        ),
    ),
```

In the database (MySQL), the field is set to INT(11).

- There is no cron job active
- I don't set the date anywhere manual (only over the extbase dependency injection mechanism)

I don't know why this happens or by what it's fired. It happend three times since the launch of the page in november.

A furthermore strange thing: Evendo all 'date'-values are updated and show now a datevalue for the 01.01.1970, the values are different (those are integers) and display exponentiations of 2 (starting at 128) or combinations of those (e.q. 1'792 (1024 + 512 + 256))

The only thing I can reproduce:
When an courseitem is moved from one system folder to another, the date for this item (but not for all, like in the other error) drops to the 1.1.1970

I would be very glad if someone could help me, even with a hint or a suspicion, what could be wrong or why that could happen. The feeling of a ticking timebomb, everytime after import another backup, isn't that shiny at all ;)

Thanks in advance
xan

Comment: I never used 'default' => time() in a TCA.. Maybe thats the problem? Try to remove the 'default' line.. As far as I know extbase sets the current time automatically if there is no 'default' => 0 ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it directly and created a new item (correct date) and moved it afterwards => wrong date again.

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version do you use? Since TYPO3 4.5 the 'checkbox' attribute on input fields isnt used anymore.. I dont think that this is a solution to your problem but i wanted to say it anyway..

Comment: I really think that 'default' => time() is the problem.. Did you cleared the whole cache after removing the line? Please remove the line and reinstall your extension or clear the cache in the install tool.. The Problem is that when you set default => time() the current timestamp is cached in the TCA and it can result in wrong default values if the system cache has not been invalidated...

Comment: TYPO3 6.2.15 is installed. The checkbox thing is a good hint, thanks. But yes, I cleared the whole cache after that, multiple times (I tried it more than once). I'll try it again, but until now there is no difference in the behaviour. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: The `'default' => time()` is only required for backend forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your last remark points to the solution:

> A furthermore strange thing: Evendo all 'date'-values are updated and show now a datevalue for the 01.01.1970, the values are different (those are integers) and display exponentiations of 2 (starting at 128) or combinations of those (e.q. 1'792 (1024 + 512 + 256))

I suspect that in the `ctrl` section of your table setup, you set the `date` field as the `sorting` column. Therefore, when moving a record, TYPO3 will change the corresponding value to ensure a correct ordering of records e.g. in the backend lists or when selecting records for frontend output. To ease inserting a record somewhere (and not having to reorder *everything* then), TYPO3 by default uses multiples of two for that.

Comment: After all this time - This has to be it! Thank you very much, indeed was the configuration set to sortby -> crashing field.
I'm going to change that immediately and keep it in mind for further projects. 
Thank you again, Mr. Wolf!

Answer (score 0):

I'd to add it as an comment, but I'm not allowed to (because of my reputation).

I expect the issue with the DateTime object from php and how it is stored within the repository. The mysql field is an int. DateTime from php is no integer, but an object. Maybe you need to convert the DateTime to a timestamp (= integer) before saving it to the database.

Comment: I dont think so because as the TYPO3 TCAReference says: "Setting the field to evaluate the input to a date returned to the database in UNIX-time (seconds)". Extbase is doing the conversion for you if you set. 'eval' => 'date',.. (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html) search for "Setting the field to evaluate the input to a date".. Correct me if I'm wrong.